# Stacked Area chart (nvd3) not showing area even though data is coming, also showing NaN for some values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

### CODE

case "ViewComponent.Web.Chart.stackedAreaChart":

//This piece of code is used to get the data

```
                var chartData1XYSize = function() {
    return nodeData
    .map(function(node) {
        return {
            key : node.fields.name,
            values : [ {
                x : convertNodeFieldValue(node, 0),
                y : convertNodeFieldValue(node, 1),
                size : convertNodeFieldValue(node, 2, 1)
            } ]
        };
    });
};
```

// This piece of code is used to get the data

```
                data = chartData1XYSize();
                console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this is the data of stackedAreachart >>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
               console.log(data);
                chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                    .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
                    .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
                    .controlLabels({stacked: "Stacked"})
                     //.interpolate("step")
                    .showControls(true)
                    .duration(300)
                    .clipEdge(true);
                chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d)) });
                chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.4f'));
                chart.legend.vers('furious');

                data.forEach(function(d,i){ 

                    d.values = d.values.sort(
                        function(a,b){
                           return +a.t -b.t;
                        }
                    );
                 });
                if (preferences.fieldList.length > 0) {
                    chart.yAxis
                    .axisLabel(
                            fieldLabel(preferences.fieldList[0].type))
                            .tickFormat(
                                    d3
                                    .format(fieldFormat(preferences.fieldList[0].type)));

                }
                break;
```

### Output of this code

[image: This is the output of the code . By introducing interactive guideline it seems to show data]

> I am not able to produce the stacked area chart as explained in this link [Stacked Area Example](https://github.com/nvd3-community/nvd3/blob/gh-pages/examples/stackedAreaChart.html)
>
> ### Data

json={"fieldList":[{"id":"cost","type":"money"},{"id":"actualCost","type":"money"},{"id":"costOverruns","type":"money"},{"id":"remainingCost","type":"money"},{"id":"remainingWork","type":"work"}],"componentIdKey":"com.projectlibre.graphic.view.ViewComponentConfiguration/node.dashboard/ViewComponent.Web.Chart.stackedAreaChart","fieldListKey":"com.projectlibre.core.field.FieldList/project.dashboard.stackedAreaChart/FieldList.Chart.stackedAreaChart.budgetCostOverruns","zoomIndex":"2","componentId":"ViewComponent.Web.Chart.stackedAreaChart"}

jsonNodes = [{"uid":"da788db8-5981-4c78-a39e-9be27195e0fb_4_2","id":1,"summary":false,"fields":{"cost":"5.0308925723E10","actualCost":"4.92707912507E11","costOverruns":"4.42398986784E11","remainingCost":"-4.42398986784E11","name":"Project1"},"intervals":[{"start":1.475571051423E12,"finish":1.476694251423E12}]},{"uid":"2c53d187-c48e-44c8-aab7-2a091fe11ad0_4_3","id":2,"summary":false,"fields":{"cost":"6.958011879E9","actualCost":"7.09454607E8","costOverruns":"0.0","remainingCost":"6.248557272E9","name":"Project2"},"intervals":[{"start":1.475571051791E12,"finish":1.475657451791E12}]},{"uid":"4e4edd23-2aaa-44f2-9811-286dfddc5ddd_4_6","id":3,"summary":false,"fields":{"cost":"6.60208339E9","actualCost":"7.01800174E8","costOverruns":"0.0","remainingCost":"5.900283216E9","name":"Project5"},"intervals":[{"start":1.475571054669E12,"finish":1.475657454669E12}]},{"uid":"c7027329-d68d-493e-a8cf-23f84c8dce28_4_1","id":4,"summary":false,"fields":{"cost":"7.692646964E9","actualCost":"5.78513824748E11","costOverruns":"5.70821177784E11","remainingCost":"-5.70821177784E11","name":"Project"},"intervals":[{"start":1.475571051063E12,"finish":1.476348651063E12}]},{"uid":"374aefc2-d9d6-4f97-bfae-c5d7618f2672_4_4","id":5,"summary":false,"fields":{"cost":"6.60208339E9","actualCost":"7.01800174E8","costOverruns":"0.0","remainingCost":"5.900283216E9","name":"Project3"},"intervals":[{"start":1.475571052612E12,"finish":1.475657452612E12}]}]

Comment: Can you just include the sample data.I think it should be d.x and d.y instead of d[0] and d[1]

Comment: @user3696882 i have added the data  which i am using for this stackedarea chart
I  tried using your suggestion but didn't turned out well